# Checking out code to a remote server via powershell

Tags: powershell, svn

I am trying to run a batch file that checks out code from a repo. This file is on a different server and i am trying to run it using powershell from my local machine after enabling remoting. when I use Invoke command nothing is returned on my powershell. If i directly try to checkout the code using svn command to the remote server i get svn access forbidden error. Is there a way to resolve this

Comment: maybe. would be great to see the part of your code which creates the error.

Comment: I have connected from computer A to B by enabling ps remoting and then as suggested by Yuan enabled wsmancredssp then using invoke-command tried svn list svnrepoURL. but it still gives forbidden error